# Catching all exceptions in windows service C#

Tags: .net, windows-services, clr, c#-2.0

Is there a way i can catch all sort of exceptions in windows services. It is like i have a service which i should keep running for ever and now if some connecting database or third party server dies for a moment i dont want my service to stop. I want that timers should give exceptions and after some time when server are up they should be working but right now exceptionn coming brings down my window service.

PS - I have read abt unhandles exception handler but i am not sure if that would stop from getting service crashed.I also have try catch block all over to catch generic exception (elapsed event handler).

Comment: can you show us your Exception handling code?

Comment: Hi Furqan..exception code is simlpe with wrapping complete elapsed event handler and catching generic exception

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. You can use [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event to generate debug info before your application crashes.

But creating your own exception handling shouldn't be that hard. All services has an entry point (`Service.OnStart`) where you launch your own thread/timer. Wrap all code in that thread/timer with a try/catch. That should catch all exceptions.

There is an exception though. Any threads/timers created in your code could still crash your application. You got to wrap all timer/thread callbacks with try/catch too.

Comment: Hi jgauffin I am already wrapping all my code in try catch exception block and catching generic exception but as soon as i disconnect LAN wire i get exception as i am connecting to sql server present in LAN and my service stops, i want that service should give exception but then as timer is still running it should be up and running.

Comment: Also this behaviour is not consistent i made a very basic service with 4 timers and i can keep that service and timer running if i disconnect but this is not happening for the actual (production) service which is performing lots of task. I am also taking into consideration the timer stop and start  before entering elapsed event.

Comment: You cant be catching exceptions in all threads/timers since you get uncaught exceptions.

Comment: ok..but i have complete elapsed event handler in try catch block and that too catching a generic exception. now i agree that exception is still coming so as per my understanding it is some unhandled exception . I am not able to understand why it comes can reason could be that unhandle exception try to open debugger window and that casue some other problem in windows service. Please guide me if my understanding is correct. I have been going through various forums but i am not getting answers

Comment: is catching exception in try catch block in elapsed handler not enough? and are there exceptions that cannot be catched i just want that my timer keeps on running in case exceptions come for few minutes.(actually here i am trying to replicate a failover scneario for a server) so that when failover of database server happens service keeps on running

Comment: Implement the `UnhandledException` event that I linked to in my answer. Write the contents of the exception to a (log)file. And you'll see where it get thrown.

Comment: ok i will do that but can u tell me that there is a possibility that exception can still go unhandled in some inner function though whole code is is try catch and we are catching a generic exception. As per my understanding it should bubble up to top if it is not getting handled in inner function. Please put your comments if my understnading is wrong in understanding that..actually the thing is i already know why exception comes ie ( i am disconecting my LAN) but it is like i want to handle and swallow it.

Comment: The only way for unhandled exceptions to go through is if they are thrown in another thread than the threads that you use try/catch on.

Comment: yes and i think other possibility could be that this elapsed event handler is calling some unmanaged API and they are throwing the exception . i will try to debug this service and find out exact place from where exceptio comes and i ma hoping putting a try catch should there should solve my problem.

Comment: Catch `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` as I said earlier. It will tell you the exception that is thrown and where (it's stacktrace)

Comment: You cannot catch and contain the ThreadAbortException via exception handlers. It will just get rethrown

Comment: @Harindaka: I did not say that either.

Comment: Good to see people sticking with it jgauffin

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got my application working by swallowing exception as it happens in .net framewroek 1.1, Below is the setting i added in app.config file.

```
<configuration> 
 <runtime> 
  <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" /> 
  </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: By doing that, you allow your application to continue running in an undefined state.  That is *not* a good idea.  It's much better to log the exception and gracefully exit if the program cannot automatically correct the problem and remain in a known good state.